# Combine two nvarchar strings into one with input on two lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-concatenation

Below code combines two strings. How do I combine BUT output them into separate lines (desired output for power bi)?

`SELECT CONCAT('a','b')`

Output: `ab`

Desired Output:

```
a
b
```

**@@VERSION:** Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: but then that's not concatenating at all...what's the input here?

Comment: You may be confusing data layer with the presentation layer.    That said, you can always print a sting with a CRLF:     print CONCAT('a',char(13)+char(10),'b')

Comment: The question is using words that contradict each other. You don't "input" values into lines. SQL has no lines to begin with. Concatenation means returning *one* value from multiple. You can split a string into multiple values with `STRING_SPLIT`.  If you wanted to return multiple hardcoded values as rows in SQL you'd use a table value constructor `SELECT val from (('a'),('b')) tbl(val varchar(10))` Somehow I doubt that's what you want though.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti you are right. My goal is to combine these two fields into one and visualize them in power bi but each one of the two fields should start on a separate line.

Comment: SQL doesn't have lines. What you call "lines" anyway is a long string with newline characters here and there. You can concatenate values separated by a separator with `CONCAT_WS`. That *won't* work in web apps because newlines are treated the same as spaces. I'm not sure how Power BI will handle this. If you want to wrap text in Power BI you'll have to configure the report.

Comment: A quick & very dirty trick in web apps is to use `<br>` as the separator. Unfortunately this can create ugly results if it clashes with the report's stylesheet

Comment: PowerBI has HTML5 rendering visual on marketplace. You could use <br/> like  @PanagiotisKanavos said.